# Assigning names to a vector retrieved by get()

Tags: r, assign

I'm having issues with giving a vector object names when the vector itself is retrieved by get. This is a very simple example of my problem. Obviously the object_names object here isn't doing anything specific but in my actual script it just pertains to what actually goes into the scores and names objects and is working perfectly fine.

```
object_names <- c('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
for (n in object_names) {
  assign(paste0(n, '_scores'), 1:5)
  assign(paste0(n, '_names'), letters[1:5])
  names(get(paste0(n, '_scores'))) <- get(paste0(n, '_names))
}
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
Error in get(paste0(n, "_scores")) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

If I go back and just type out the command myself after the fact it obviously works, but I'd prefer to be able to do this in a more automated fashion. Is there perhaps a way to use assign() function to set the names attribute of a vector? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `get` here at all:

```r
object_names <- c('test1', 'test2', 'test3')

for (n in object_names) {
  scores <- 1:5
  names(scores) <- letters[1:5]
  assign(paste0(n, '_scores'), scores)
  assign(paste0(n, '_names'), names(scores))
}

test1_scores
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5

test1_names
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Note though, that if you have a bunch of similar objects with similar names, you will save yourself a lot of time and effort if you put your objects in lists rather than assigning them to the global environment:

```r
object_names <- c('test1', 'test2', 'test3')

setNames(lapply(object_names, function(x) setNames(1:5, letters[1:5])),
         paste0(object_names, "_score"))
#> $test1_score
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5 
#> 
#> $test2_score
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5 
#> 
#> $test3_score
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>